# On change show alert C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check if else condition works on the asp.net C# code behind what am not getting is on dropdown change there is a condition if selected index value is zero then alrt 0 alert but nothing shows on any of the selected index is selected not sure where am i going wrong.

CS: Code Behind

```
  protected void Student_type_dd_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Student_type_dd.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('0');</script>");
            }
            else if (Student_type_dd.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('1');</script>");
            }
            else if (Student_type_dd.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('2');</script>");
            }

        }
```

Aspx

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="Student_type_dd" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="Student_type_dd_change" autopostback="true" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select Type" Value="0" />
                      <asp:ListItem Text="All Students" Value="All Students" />
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Class Wise" Value="Class Wise" />
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Select Specific" Value="Select Specific" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger instead of using javascript to output something?

Comment: @StephenBrickner Doesn't `Response.Write` write it to the content of the postback?

Comment: Given the description of the problem and the code we're seeing here, I suspect it's ***very likely*** that you're over-writing the `DropDownList` values (and, consequently, the selected index) in `Page_Load`.  As others are suggesting, this is also a *terrible* way to "debug" your code.  Use the actual debugger that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: @Rawling yes actually I think so. It's been a while since the days of postbacks. But either way I think you have to turn off the validation on the request to allow js to run like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('0')", true);
```

Comment: Can i ask you a quick question if you dont mind?? and the above worked thanks

Comment: @Shaik: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.  You don't have to ask permission to ask a question.  The entire purpose of this site is to ask and answer questions.

Comment: Sure, if I can't answer maybe somebody else will.

Comment: @David Cool My question was say the above script slows the alert in case if i have to call a java script from Code behind how will that be

Comment: @Shaik: It's not really clear what you're asking.  The code in this answer is one approach for invoking JavaScript code in the page based on server-side logic, depending on when/how you want to invoke that code.  There are other approaches, also depending on when/how you want to invoke that code.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, I'll guess you are asking if you can call a javascript method this way. Yes, just replace alert('0') with the method name.